# Eclipse: Fulltext autocompletion for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

can I has fulltext autocompletion for Java @ Eclipse? Let's demonstrate:

**Final piece of code:**

```
getVariants().add(new Variant(MediaType.TEXT_XML));
```

**How do I code now:**

> getv[ctrl+space].a[Enter]new
>   V[ctrl+space, down arrow,
>   Enter]M[Ctrl+Space, Enter].**text_x**

Basically, Eclipse completes word "TEXT_XML" when I provide letters "TEXT_X".

**How would I like to code:**

> getv[ctrl+space].a[Enter]new
>   V[ctrl+space, down arrow,
>   Enter]M[Ctrl+Space, Enter].**xml**

and Eclipse should realise I meant "TEXT_XML" (fulltext autocompletion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, **there is no way of enabling a full-text code completion in the Eclipse preferences view**. This has been bugging me for a while, too. I did quite a bit of digging and I'm pretty certain there is no easy way of achieving this.

However,
there are two ways of implementing the desired, but I assume both of which are way to much work for fixing this little nuisance.

1. There is an Eclipse plug-in extension point for the JDT Java Completion Proposal Computer - [reference page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html)
   A sample project which implements this extension point can be found [in this repository](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/).
   This is fairly convenient, <s>but still a lot of boilerplate and tedious coding.</s>
2. You can change the `findKeywords` method in the internal [org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.CompletionEngine](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/codecoverage/B01/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist/CompletionEngine.java.html) class and compile your own JDT fork. But this is discouraged for so many reasons. First of all, this class is a 12000 line monster and hard to just jump in. And of course, if you'd only hack a kludge in, there is little chance of this becoming an official contribution, so you'd need to worry about every eclipse release.

Additionally, there might be a very chillaxed way in the future. Although this might exceed your requirements a bit.

Have a look at the [Code Recommenders project](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/). This [blog](http://code-recommenders.blogspot.com) has an [outline of the project objectives](http://code-recommenders.blogspot.com/2010/05/its-all-about-intelligent-code.html)
It doesn't mention full-text auto-completion specifically, but I'd assume its matching algorithms go even beyond that.

**Edit**: In the proper SO-spirit, I'll keep this answer up to date:

Apparently the feature is now implemented in the Code Recommenders plug-in. See this  [blog post](http://code-recommenders.blogspot.com/2011/05/subword-matching-completion-engine-for.html) and this [forum thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/209269/). I'm quite surprised it only took 10 locs. To me the extension point appeared more complex.

Comment: I just wanted to say, that Code Recommenders is pretty useful after using it for a while :)

Comment: @Xorty: I've updated my answer with two links relating to this, just to justify the bounty ;) I assume you are the OP of that eclipse forum thread anyway. How are your experiences with the plug-in so far? Is it safe enough for production?

Comment: It's me yes :-) Actually I have some troubles so far, sometimes recommenders plugin carshes (I don't remember this happening before this feature) :-(. But my Eclipse is now MONSTEr with gazillion of plugins, I am going to use seoncd eclipse installations and test it more. I'll post some feedback to Eclipse forums.

Comment: Thanks for this, I just made a blog guide to installing and configuring recommenders on 2014 eclipse. http://www.equipcodes.com/1/post/2014/01/fulltext-autocomplete-in-eclipse-for-java-android-development.html

Answer (score 2):

If your MediaType class does not contain a large number of accessible fields/methods you could simply use

```
getv[ctrl+space].a[Enter]new V[ctrl+space, down arrow, Enter]M[Ctrl+Space, Enter].[Ctrl+Space, down arrow, Enter]
```

you may need to press the down arrow more than once, though to select the desired field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can using Templates. (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates)

The basic usage is you set the name to what you want to type and you set the pattern to what you want to appear.

In my testing I set the name to `xml`, the Context to `Java`, the Pattern to `TEXT_XML` and Automatically insert turned on. Then when I typed out your example I was able to follow a pattern like...

`getv[ctrl+space].a[enter]new V[ctrl+space, down arrow, Enter]M[ctrl+Space, Enter].xml[ctrl+space]`

and since Automatically insert was turned on *poof* TEXT_XML was inserted.

Templates have much more functionality than that and the one source I used for this answer was [Effective Eclipse](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ).

I hope this helps!

Comment: You would have to manually configure the pattern for every single member though right?  And you couldn't instead search for "ml" and get TEST_XML without configuring that as well?  I think the OP is looking for something a little more dynamic.

Comment: @Mark Peters: True, I considered the question to be looking for a solution to reducing repetitive key strokes. Still Templates are good to know about :D

Comment: That's nice feature thanks for suggestion, but unfortunatelly it is not what I am looking for (question s about fulltext autocompletion).